# How to insert text into database table if we write any thing on multiselect ?

Tags: php

i already made a box in which skills are multiselected if we type something in text box,but i want to add those skills which are not inside my database that user type.
my question is how i make that?
my code is-

```
  <span class="pf-title">skills</span>                                          
      <div class="pf-field no-margin">

   <select id="lstFruits"multiple="multiple"class="chosen"name="skill[]" 
              data-placeholder="Please Select Skill">
     <?php 
           $fetch="SELECT * FROM `skill`";
            $record=mysqli_query($conn,$fetch);
            while($records_row=mysqli_fetch_array($record))
            {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $records_row['skill_name'];?>"<? 
                 php foreach($sk as $s){if($records_row['skill_name'] == $s) 
                  { echo 'selected="selected"';}}?>><?php echo 
                    $records_row['skill_name'];?></option>
                 <?php  }
                 ?>
             </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
<select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple" class="chosen" name="skill[]" data-placeholder="Please Select Skill">
        <?php

            $fetch="SELECT * FROM `skill`";
            $record=mysqli_query($conn,$fetch);

            $flag = false;

            while($records_row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)){          
                foreach($sk as $s){
                    if($records_row['skill_name'] == $s) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$records_row['skill_name'].'" selected="selected">'.$records_row['skill_name'].'</option>';
                        $flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!$flag) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$records_row['skill_name'].'">'.$records_row['skill_name'].'</option>';                  
                }
                $flag = false;
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: no its not working your code gives only selection of simple skills from data base but i need multiple selection of skills from data base(that i already done) with user can also give his/her  skil by typing on text field  if that skill is not in my data base then that skill add to my database (need)

Comment: Then use ajax to  insert that skill into database and then add that value in drop down. $('#lstFruits').append('<option value="">value</value>');